# Its possible add User Roles on Wordpress by API REST?

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

Im adding users with JSON but i need to create user roles too for this specific users by API REST, this is poossible ?

So much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, by performing a GET request to “wp-json/wp/v2/users”

You can define it using the below example:

```
 {
    "username" : "rockstar",
    "first_name" : "Seace",
    "last_name" : "Kaka",
    "email" : "myuser@example.com",
    "password" : "Password123!",
    "roles" : ["your_role"]
}
```

To verify the obvious details, just review the documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but when i try to post user or create with other role:

"rest_user_invalid_role"

Comment: you have to define the role inside the configuration of users

Comment: My question is if it is possible define roles or create new roles by API